# I can't seem to figure out how to display something through nested loops

Tags: python, loops

I'm almost finished with a program for school, but I am unable to figure out what else I need to have. Here's the problem:

> Write a program that uses nested loops to collect data and calculate
>   the average rainfall over a period of years. The program should first
>   ask for the number of years. The outer loop will iterate once for each
>   year. The inner loop will iterate twelve times, once for each month.
>   Each iteration of the inner loop will ask the user for the inches of
>   rainfall for that month. After all iterations, the program should
>   display the number of months, the total inches of rainfall, and the
>   average rainfall per month for the entire period.

I used the first loop to iterate for each year, and the second for the months, which would be 12. Inside the month loop, I ask for how many inches of rainfall and I make each iteration equal to TotalYearlyRainfall, so that it adds it to the variable. I make a new variable called grandTotal to equal TotalYearlyRainfall.

```
for xxx in range(1,13):
```

this is my third loop to work inside of the table, and I made xxx the variable to count each iteration to display each month in the left column.

```
print (xxx,"              ",Rainfall(xx))
```

I'm not sure what to do with the second area here, to display what the user has entered in the second loop for each month. I'm really just guessing at this point as to what to put and see if it works.

Here is my source code:

```
Years = int(input("Enter the number of years.")) #Based on user input, the loop will iterate 'Years' times.
TotalYearlyRainfall = 0 #define properly
grandTotal = 0 #define properly
for x in range(1,Years+1): #How many years
    for xx in range(1,13): #The months in each
        Rainfall = int(input(("How many inches of rainfall for month ",xx,"/12?")))
        TotalYearlyRainfall += Rainfall #T.Y.R is equal to Rainfall, as it adds each Rainfall.
        grandTotal = TotalYearlyRainfall
        #print (TotalYearlyRainfall)
print ("Months       Rainfall(in)") #Table
print ("-------------------------") #Table
for xxx in range(1,13): #months
    print (xxx,"              ",Rainfall(xx)) #I am stuck on this line...
print ("-------------------------") #Table
print ("Total Rainfall: ",grandTotal) #prints the grandTotal
Average = grandTotal / xx
print ("Average(in): ",Average) #Average amount of rainfall per month

'''
if 1-12 inputted for each
consecutive month,

Total: 78 inches.
Average: 6.5 inches.
'''
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you printing a table?  It doesn't seem to say you need to in the prompt.  I was thinking number of months: 12, total 144, average: 12

Comment: I'm printing a table to organize and make the outputs look better, it just takes a couple more seconds and isn't too hard to deal with anyways. Ok, but I am having trouble on how I should display what the user enters in the second for loop outside of the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After all iterations, the program should display the number of
>   months, the total inches of rainfall, and the average rainfall per
>   month for the entire period.

So all you really need to do is print three number:

1. The total number of months
2. The total amount of rain that fell over the whole period
3. The average amount that fell each month (i.e. number 1 / number 2)

You'll need to fix your code a little bit though, as at the moment your grand total is overwritten after each month, and you've got too many brackets when asking for the number of years. You also don't need the total yearly rainfall figure at all! Try:

```
Years = int(input("Enter the number of years: ")) #Based on user input, the loop will iterate 'Years' times.
grandTotal = 0 #define properly

for x in range(1,Years+1): #How many years
    for xx in range(1,13): #The months in each
        Rainfall = int(input("How many inches of rainfall for month "+str(xx)+"/12: "))
        grandTotal += Rainfall #add that months rainfall to the total

Months = Years*12 #works out the number of months
Average = grandTotal/(Years*12) #works out the average

print ("Number of months (months): ", Months) #prints the total number of months
print ("Total Rainfall (in): ",grandTotal) #prints the grandTotal
print ("Average Rainfall (in per month): ",Average) #Average amount of rainfall per month
```

Comment: Oh... I see now. Most problems I get asked are worded weirdly for me, and sometimes I just an explanation from somebody else of what exactly it's asking of me. Thank you so much :) I see where I went wrong.

Comment: I just have trouble understanding the whole Variable += OtherVariable types of things, and how each iteration effects it and such. I'll have to look deeper into it I guess.

Comment: That's a pleasure. `variable += other_variable` is just a shorter way of writing `variable = variable + other_variable`. They both do exactly the same thing; you're just adding the value of `other_variable` to `variable`! Rubber duck debugging may help you with similar problems in the future - try explaining your question to a rubber duck. Whilst they can't tell you the answer, sometimes simplifying the question helps!